# Showing a division justification?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know this question may seem to trivial to discuss but here goes.

Let A,B,C be positive integers.

**Propostion**

*If A divides B then A divides BC.*

**Explanation**

Let

$B=AK$ K is integer

Consquently

$BC=(AK C)$

Anything that has A as a factor. Can be divided by A.

Therefore A divides BC.

Comment: More explicitly $\, BC = (AK)C = A(KC)\ $ is divisible by $\,A,\,$ where we used the *associative* law to pull out the factor $A,\ \ $

Comment: Herstein's topics in algebra goes over many basic results such as this before moving on to group theory and beyond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's basically correct. I might be a little more explicit at the end: since $BC = AKC = A(KC)$ and both $K$ and $C$ are integers, so is $KC$; therefore $A$ divides $BC$.